# Labels are not shown for HeaderRenderer

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, renderer

I want my datagrid header to be rendered with date labels. I am using following code for the same. However my lables are not visible when I run actual application. Can anyone please suggest?

```
import mx.controls.Label;
public class HeaderRenderer extends Label
{                                                                                          
private var lbl:Label;                                                                 
private const LEFT_PADDING:int = 12;                                                     

public function HeaderRenderer()
{
  super();
  lbl = new Label();
  lbl.visible=true;
  lbl.text="Label";
}
override protected function updateDisplayList(w:Number, h:Number):void
{
    lbl.x = LEFT_PADDING;
}
```

I am accessing it from datagrid column as below.

```
<mx:columns>
    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="title" headerText="Task" width="{taskHeaderWidth}"/>
    <mx:DataGridColumn  itemRenderer="{ganttItemEditor}" 
             headerRenderer="{new ClassFactory(HeaderRenderer)}"
             rendererIsEditor="true"
             />
    </mx:columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code may help u: -

```
package
{
    import mx.controls.listClasses.MXItemRenderer;
    import spark.components.Label;
    public class HeaderRenderer extends MXItemRenderer
    {
        private const LEFT_PADDING:int = 12;                                                     
        private var lbl:Label;   

        public function HeaderRenderer()
        {
            super();
            lbl = new Label();
            lbl.visible=true;
            lbl.text="Label";
            this.addElement(lbl);
        }

        override protected function updateDisplayList(w:Number, h:Number):void
        {
            super.updateDisplayList(w, h);
            lbl.x = LEFT_PADDING;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I analyzed it, issue is with eclipse compiler and it is showing that build is successful with no errors but it is picking old files only. I tried doing clean build, changing eclipse workspace,importing project again.. but with no fruitful results :(